# Android Database in background

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, oop

I am having a bit problem with my android database. Basically the problem is that when i retrieve my values from the database when the activity is running it runs fine but when my application is on the back ground and i have used a broadcast class so when an sms is received
my it passed the value to activity and it has to receive data from database(SQLite) i crashes the problem is that database only retrive  data when app activity is running so my qestions is that how can i retrive from the database when my app is in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) running all the time. Service runs your activities tasks in the background.Without the need to display activity view.

Comment: Suppose i want to receive a broadcast about incoming phone calls. and i want to reject those calls matching to a paticular number.
So what i ll do is, keep a service running in background. and when a call recieve the broadcast receiver get notified and it ll reject my call.
so i ll create a service first.,start the service,
recieve notification,
reject call,
stop the service if i wanted

Comment: here is a simple tutorial for that http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html